# Not getting desired output in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Customer(cid, cname, caddress, cphone, balance)
Movie(mid, title, genre, year)
Branch(bid, bname, baddress)
Copy(copyid, mid, bid)
Rental(cid, copyid, outdate, returndate, cost)
```

List all customer who have rented “Terminator 1” and “Terminator 2” but not “Terminator 3”.

This is my answer, but output is not right:

```
SELECT r.cid from (Rental r natural join Copy c), Movie m 
WHERE c.mid=m.mid and m.title="Terminator 1" and m.title="Terminator2" and m.title<>"Terminator 3"
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question ..

Comment: Can you add which database you are working on?

Comment: How is your output _not right_?  Can you show us your result and your desired result?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Wamp server. it's not executing the not part(terminator 3)

Comment: `m.title="Terminator 1" and m.title="Terminator2"` is an invalid statement.  The `title` column of the `m` table will never equal both "Terminator 1" and "Terminator2".  If you want to know which records could have either of those values, use an `OR` instead.